# node.js не подгружается require

Tags: node.js

Подскажите что не так - есть два файла, server.js и config.json, оба в одной папке.

В server.js прописано:

```
var config = require('config');
```

При запуске server.js получаю ошибку Error: Cannot find module 'config'

Но есть пропишу так:

```
var config = require('./config');
```

то работает, однако мне нужен первый вариант так как есть вложенные папки где мне нужно использовать config, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант `require('config')` указывает на использование подключенных библиотек, у них глобальная область видимости.

У второго варианта `require('./config')` есть `./`, которая говорит использовать текущую папку и можно указать файл.
Относительно текущей папки можно перемещаться вглубь папок `require('./test/test')`
Также можно перемещаться вверх на один уровень вложенности с помощью `../`, напр. если вы создали дочернюю папку `myfolder`, внутри нее используете `require('./../config')`

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант:

```
require.main.require('./config')
```

Этот способ ищет модуль config.js, находящийся в той же директории что и главный модуль.

В более сложных случаях можно воспользоваться библиотекой [rfr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfr) (это отдельная библиотека, ее можно скачать через `npm install rfr`):

```
var rfr = require('rfr');
rfr('config');
```

Эта библиотека ищет модули относительно папки, которая на 2 уровня выше той, куда она была установлена.

Для простых проектов этого будет достаточно, но если вы пишите библиотеку - вам надо не забыть добавить `rfr` в [`bundledDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies), чтобы она была автоматически поставлена в нужную вам папку когда вашу библиотеку скачают.

---

Но я бы рекомендовал все же использовать относительные пути. Почему? Потому что IDE. Если вы будете использовать IDE - то она скорее всего попросту не поймет что за модуль вы загружаете нестандартным способом.

Относительные же пути работают в любых IDE которые поддерживают модули.

Answer (score 0):

Если по какой-то причине не хочется писать"./*", то надо создать папку **node_modules** и положить папку со своим модулем туда, это особенность работы модуля *require*, по умолчанию он ищет файлы в папках **node_modules**, сначала из дериктории запуска скрипта, дальше вроде бы проверят стандартные библиотеки Node.JS.
и помоему правильнее config подгружать так

> var config = require('config.json');

Answer (score -1):

Так собственно в чем проблема? "./" - это путь к той же директория где расположен скрипт. Значит у тебя config.js и server.js на одном уровне. Если другой скрипт лежит в другой папке то тебе просто придется прописать относительный путь к config.js

Вот и все.

Comment: Если бы вы читали вопрос внимательнее, то увидели бы, что автор знает про относительные пути - и хочет их избежать.